# Minimum of random exponential variable and time

Tags: probability

Let $U$ and $V$ be $\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$.
Let $s \in [0, t)$.

Does this reasoning from left to hold:
$P(U + (V \wedge t) \leq s) = P(U + V \leq s; V < t) $ or is in this case enough to write (as our tutor did)
$P(U + V \leq s)$.

I do not think that the latter is correct, since random variable $V$ is defined on $(0,\infty)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $\Longrightarrow$ mean in this context?

Comment: And what does $(V \mbox{ min }  t)$ mean?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\{U + V \leq s \} \cap \{V < t\} \subseteq \{U + \min[V,t] \leq s\}$, which is true.  But then I do not see a question in what you write.

Comment: I have edited my question. $(V \min t)$ was supposed to be $\min(V,t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that where you wrote $P(U + (V \min t) \leq s) \implies P(U + V \leq s; V < t)$, you meant "$=$".

If the two probabilities are indeed equal, it seems likely that it's because the two events $[U+\min\{V,t\}\le s]$ and $[U+V\le s\ \&\ V<t]$ are equal, or at least differ by an event whose probability is $0$.

There are two cases to consider:
$$
\begin{cases}
\cdots\cdots & \text{if }V<t, \\
\cdots\cdots & \text{if }V>t.
\end{cases}
$$
(We need not consider $V=t$ since the probability of that is $0$.)
$$
[U + \min\{V,t\}\le s] = \begin{cases} [U+V\le s] & \text{if }V<t, \\[6pt] [U + t \le s] & \text{if }V>t. \end{cases}
$$
But we have not yet used the fact that $s<t$, which was given at the outset.  Since $U>0$, the event $[U+t\le s]$ is impossible.  Hence if $V>t$, then the event whose probability we seek cannot happen.  Therefore it is equivalent to $[U+V\le s\ \&\ V<t]$.

Comment: I completely understand the explanation above for which I am really thankful. So the answer $[U + V \leq s]$ is in this case not correct?

Comment: Actually $[U+V\le s]$ would imply that $V<t$, so that appears to be correct. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If we would like to calculate the exact probability, are we integrating over the same area in both cases?

Comment: Yes.  (Except for possible boundaries whose measure is $0$, and those won't affect the value of the integral.) ${}\qquad{}$